# Flow Block Utilization service block displayed on bar chart

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to get the service block created into a flow block to display utilization output in a bar chart.

I have tried the following code with service block

```
  PP_T.utilization()
```

It did work with the service block, however, when I have created a flow block contain a service block the code didn't work. Not sure how to solve this issue?

[Flow Block and Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cbCl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Service` block is a pre-designed block that provides a `utilization()` function.

Your custom flow blocks are agents *you*  created, so it is your responsibility to provide a `utilization()` function. You can easily add one to your `SubProcess` agent type and make it compute whatever represents Utilization.

PS: Do study how OOP, functions, etc. work in AnyLogic and Java in general. Do all the step-by-step tutorials for a start, explore the example models...

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a resource pool is the simplest answer for monitoring the utilization of a service block within a custom flow block using a bar graph in main. Please see image foe illustration.
[Custom flow with service block and resource pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l8Tk.png)

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4567.png)